# Show entire row for duplicates

Tags: duplicates

I can find the duplicates in rawHR table, but now need to show all of the remaining columns of those duplicates.  Here's what I've tried, but it gives me all employees, not just the duplicate ones.

select *
from rawHR
where exists
    (
        select distinct firstname, lastname
        from rawHR
        group by firstname, lastname
        having count(*)> 1
    )

Comment: I'm new to this site, so i don't know how to format.

Comment: Just for learning sake...I can do it with a JOIN...but shouldn't it work with EXISTS?